# Log shipping between 2 SQL server 2008 database servers without opening any ports?

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-shipping

Is it possible to set up  Log shipping between 2 SQL server 2008 database servers without opening any ports?

One of SQL server is in Data center and another on Local server room and both are connected with internet.

we want to enable Log shipping between them without assigning Public IP to SQL server which is in local server room which is behind firewall and without opening ports.

Instead should I use Transaction Replication and transfer snapshots through FTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you can already FTP from one server to another then you can do transaction log shipping. You'll just need a way to automate the sending over of the transaction log files via FTP. Should be pretty easy to code up.